# Using 'over' function results in column "table.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm currently writing an application which shows the growth of the total number of events in my table over time, I currently have the following query to do this:

```py
query = session.query(
    count(Event.id).label('count'),
    extract('year', Event.date).label('year'),
    extract('month', Event.date).label('month')
).filter(
    Event.date.isnot(None)
).group_by('year', 'month').all()
```

This results in the following output:

| Count | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021 | 1 |
| 50 | 2021 | 2 |
| 75 | 2021 | 3 |

While this is okay on it's own, I want it to display the total number over time, so not just the number of events that month, so the desired outpout should be:

| Count | Year | Month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 2021 | 1 |
| 150 | 2021 | 2 |
| 225 | 2021 | 3 |

I read on various places I should use a window function using SqlAlchemy's [over](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html?highlight=over#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.over) function, however I can't seem to wrap my head around it and every time I try using it I get the following error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.GroupingError) column "event.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT count(event.id) OVER (PARTITION BY event.date ORDER...
                     ^
[SQL: SELECT count(event.id) OVER (PARTITION BY event.date ORDER BY EXTRACT(year FROM event.date), EXTRACT(month FROM event.date)) AS count, EXTRACT(year FROM event.date) AS year, EXTRACT(month FROM event.date) AS month 
FROM event 
WHERE event.date IS NOT NULL GROUP BY year, month]
```

This is the query I used:

```py
session.query(
    count(Event.id).over(
        order_by=(
            extract('year', Event.date),
            extract('month', Event.date)
        ),
        partition_by=Event.date
    ).label('count'),
    extract('year', Event.date).label('year'),
    extract('month', Event.date).label('month')
).filter(
    Event.date.isnot(None)
).group_by('year', 'month').all()
```

Could someone show me what I'm doing wrong? I've been searching for hours but can't figure out how to get the desired output as adding event.id in the group by would stop my rows from getting grouped by month and year

---

The final query I ended up using:

```
query = session.query(
    extract('year', Event.date).label('year'),
    extract('month', Event.date).label('month'),
    func.sum(func.count(Event.id)).over(order_by=(
        extract('year', Event.date),
        extract('month', Event.date)
    )).label('count'),
).filter(
    Event.date.isnot(None)
).group_by('year', 'month')
```

Comment: The issue is that window functions operate on the other columns returned by the query... so you can do what you want with two columns. First `count(event.id) AS event_count` and then add `SUM(event_count) OVER (...)`

Comment: @melcher I tried this, but it results in a `column "event_count" does not exist` error for some reason, it can't find the column I just created using the `AS` statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you want, but I'm assuming you want the number of events up to that month for each month. You're going to first need to calculate the # of events per month and also sum them with the [postgresql window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html).

You can do that with in a single select statement:

```sql
SELECT extract(year FROM events.date) AS year
  , extract(month FROM events.date) AS month
  , SUM(COUNT(events.id)) OVER(ORDER BY extract(year FROM events.date), extract(month FROM events.date)) AS total_so_far
FROM events
GROUP BY 1,2
```

but it might be easier to think about if you split it into two:

```sql
SELECT year, month, SUM(events_count) OVER(ORDER BY year, month)
FROM (
  SELECT extract(year FROM events.date) AS year
    , extract(month FROM events.date) AS month
    , COUNT(events.id) AS events_count
  FROM events
  GROUP BY 1,2
)
```

but not sure how to do that in SqlAlchemy

Comment: I managed to build the first query you mentioned using SqlAlchemy and that seems to have done the trick :), I'll add it to my answer